# git-p4 and detached branches

Tags: git, branch, perforce, git-p4

So, I do a

```
git config git-p4.branchList foo/bar:baz/garply
git init
git p4 sync //depot/foo/bar
git p4 sync --branch=baz/garply //depot/baz/garply
```

When all was said and done, I was hoping that there would be relationship between foo/bar (the master branch) and baz/garply (the branch off of the master branch).  There wasn't.

I am able to `git checkout master` and I correctly land in the master branch.  But, when I try to switch to "baz/garply" `git checkout p4/baz/garply`, I land in a detached HEAD.  (`git diff master` from this detached HEAD also seems to result in very incorrect results.)

I assume that `git-p4` does not maintain relationships primarily through the `branchList` mechanism?  Is there a way to establish this relationship between the branches?

(Note that I am doing `git sync` rather than `git clone` because of the repositories are huge and I'd rather not check them out again.  Also, the detect-branches mechanism won't work because the repository is too large.)

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had an answer for you that actually works, because I need one too.

I edited `.git/info/grafts` to have a line like this:

```
HASH1 HASH2
```

in which HASH1 is the first commit on the garply branch, and HASH2 was garply's parent on master.

Problem is that now I can't `git p4 sync` or `git p4 submit` and have it actually work.

Comment: Generally, if you don't have a proposed solution, you should not post an answer. Keep it to the comments :-)